# Python variable in css

Tags: python, html, css, flask

For a project, I'm trying to get an absolute position of an image (to a background image) in an HTML file while the calculation for the position is done in Python.

This is what I passed into Flask with Python:

```
return render_template('map.html',posx=pos_x, posy=pos_y)
```

while pos_x and pos_y have values between 0 and 1260 (the height and width of the backround); and this is what i wrote in css and html

```
.img-container { position: relative; }

.img-container .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: posx;
  left: posy;
  z-index: 3     
}
</style>
 <td>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="top" src="/static/images/map_test1.png" height="70" width="70" alt="">
    <img class="bottom" src="/static/images/map_test.png" alt="">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using flask, a web python framework, you need to put `{{}}` around your variables you are passing in to your html page.

Comment: I tried that too, but it still wont work! 
But thanks for the advice!

Comment: What is the value of posx and posy? If the posx and posy were just numbers they have to be a string with css length units (see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) For example '1260px'

Comment: Yes they were just values! Thanks, now it works! But why can i find people who dont need to use the "px"?

Comment: Px is not as popular as other units because it isn't dynamic. You can use other units such as em or %.